# UIScrollView scrolling lags

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

[image]

I Have UIScrollView and a few (about 10 "posts"). 
Post - custom view with UILabe loaded from nib and dinamically changed frame.
So I do:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AWPostShortView" 
                              owner:self 
                            options:nil]; 

// calculate frame etc (doesn't matter)
self.shortPost.frame = frame;

// Add to scrollView
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.shortPost];

self.shortPost = nil;
```

**The problem** is that "scrolling" action has lags.
 
I mean - **scroll view follow under cursor with delay**
I do not any operations, calculations etc when posts appears.

Please, advise how to optimize it 
*(I can't use UITableView and reuse cells coz I have different cells heights)*

Comment: Not sure about your actual question, but you definitely can use UITableView with variable height cells: look up `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I can't use tableView becouse I have to show next row's posts right under previous row's posts

Comment: are you overriding `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Looks like u have jittery affect. This could be because of your dynamic frames. Make your frames static for a test run and see if you get the same affect. I am sure they should have a smooth transition.